# Creating a BMI calculator in flutter: defining BoxConstraints in constraints but it always shows "The named parameter 'constraints' isn't defined. "

Tags: android, ios, flutter, constraints

```
class RoundIconButton extends StatelessWidget {
  
const RoundIconButton(this.icon, this.onPress);

final Function onPress;
final IconData icon;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialButton(
      child: Icon(icon),
      elevation: 3,
      onPressed: onPress,
        **constraints:** BoxConstraints.tightFor(
          width: 56.0,
          height: 56.0,
        ),

    );
  }
}
```

constraint in bold error:

> The named parameter 'constraints' isn't defined.
> (undefined_named_parameter at [bmi_calculator]
> lib\input_page.dart:167)

Answer (score 0):

`MaterialButton` has no property `constraints`. You should wrap the button in a `ConstrainedBox`:

```
ConstrainedBox(
  constraints: const BoxConstraints.tightFor(
    width: 56.0,
    height: 56.0,
  ),
  child: MaterialButton(
    child: Icon(icon),
    elevation: 3,
    onPressed: onPress,
  ),
);
```

Comment: Its also not showing in ConstrainedBox in wrap drop down menu.

Comment: @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialButton(
      child: Icon(icon),
      elevation: 3,
      onPressed: onPress,
      shape: CircleBorder(),
      fillcolor: Color(0xFF4C4F5E),
    );
  }
} Can you help me out with this one also fillColor is also showing same error. error: The named parameter 'fillcolor' isn't defined. (undefined_named_parameter at [bmi_calculator] lib\input_page.dart:169)

Comment: I am not sure what you are saying, maybe you should update your question to indicate what exactly you want to achieve and what you have tried to do so, then we can propose a way to accomplish it.

Comment: I am not figuring out how to wrap it with a Constrained Box and after this i added a new property of fillColor. It is also showing the same error
}error: The named parameter 'fillColor' isn't defined. (undefined_named_parameter at [bmi_calculator] lib\input_page.dart:170)